# Pandas reading excel and appending output to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I am creating a function using pathlib to iterate a directory containing excel files.  I want to read through each file (1 to n files) and append column data into a list.  I can't seem to get the append logic correct during the for loop.  Files are in a dir called "**input_files**".

Here is my code:

```
def get_file_list():
    all_files = []
    hc_files = pathlib.Path("input_files/").iterdir()

    for file in hc_files:
        xl_workbook = pd.ExcelFile("input_files/{}".format(file.name))
        df = xl_workbook.parse(sheet_name=0)
        
        files = df['Path'].tolist()
        all_files.extend(files)
    
    return all_files
```

In each file there is a column called "**Path**" which contains file paths that i want to put in a list during the for loop.  I want to append and grow the list until all the of files are processed.  I have tried "append" and "extend" and created the all_files list but can't get a full list of each files directories.

Comment: `all_files = pd.concat([pd.ExcelFile(file).parse(sheet_name=0) for file in Path('input_files').rglob('*.xlsx')], ignore_index=True)['Path'].tolist()`. However, `Path('input_files').rglob('*.xlsx')` is relative the current working directory. If you're not sure, use the full path instead of `'input_files'`

Comment: Thanks @TrentonMcKinney!  That definitely helped.  Newish at Python and am trying to understand what exactly is going on in that single line.  Can you provide it in a traditional For Loop? It would help me learn.

Comment: Was also thinking of different solutions.  Do i even need pandas?  Should I use lists instead since ultimately my function is returning a list.  Seems like I may be taking an unnecessary step using a dataframe

Comment: Yes, it can be solved without pandas, but not with a single line of code. In the list-comprehension, you are creating a list of dataframes from the files found by rglob. concat combines them all into a single dataframe. the `['Path']` column is selected and converted to a list.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you deconstruct into reqular for loop?